# What is the distribution of $T$ random variable if the sample is not coming from a normal population?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be an iid sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. 
Then the distribution of 
$$
Z_{n} 
= 
\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
$$
is exactly $N(0,1)$ assuming that $\sigma$ is known.

If $\sigma$ is unknown then the distribution of 
$$
T_{n} 
= 
\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}
$$
is a $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

If $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be an iid sample from a distribution
(not necessarily normal) then the distribution of
$$
W_{n} 
= 
\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
$$
is approximately $N(0,1)$ if $n$ is large by Central Limit Theorem.

But I have not seen any theorems mentioning the distribution of the quantity
$$
U_{n} 
= 
\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}.
$$

If the value of $n$ is large then again by CLT the distribution
of $U_n$ is approximately $N(0,1)$ but assume that $n$ is not large enough
to apply the CCLT. 
Then, what is the distribution of $U_n$ (assuming $n$ is not large)?
Is it still $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom?

Moreover, what is the distribution of 
$$
V_{n} 
= 
\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
$$
if the sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is not coming from a normal population?

I am totally lost here.

Comment: For $V_n$ for $n$ large enough you can apply CLT and get normal random variates.

$U_n = T_n$ so it is also a students t distribution, unless some typo was made.

Comment: @fGDu94: $T_n$ is defined assuming the sample is coming from a normal population but for $U_n$ the population is not normal. Otherwise, they are the same. 
For the distribution of $V_n$ and $U_n$, I am taking about small sample -- not for large sample and then the use CLT.

Comment: @fGDu94: Or, do you have a reference saying $U_n$ is also $N(0,1)$ even if the sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is not coming from a normal population and $n$ is not large?

Comment: What is the difference between $V_n$ and $W_n$?

Comment: $U_n$ in general will not be a $t$-distribution. I doubt there is a name for its distribution in specific other cases.

Comment: @angryavian: Again the difference between $W_n$ and $V_n$ is whether the population is normal and the sample size is enough to apply CLT or not.